# plupload: Filters object property doesn't filter file types in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-upload, plupload

The following code snippet from this page doesn't filter file types in Google Chrome, yet it seems to filter file types in Mozilla and Internet Explorer.  It uses the plupload API.  The filter shows "My File Types" in Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox, but shows "Custom Files" in Google Chrome.  What is different in Google Chrome's file upload dialog?  How can I fix this with plupload?  My workaround is to remove "filters" altogether, or change the "files of type" dropdown option from "Custom Files" to "All Files" in Google Chrome.

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/Mar/12/Using-plUpload-to-upload-Files-with-ASPNET

.... click "Source Code for this Article on GitHub" to download source code.  I modified a few things.

Code:

```
$("#Uploader").pluploadQueue({
    runtimes: 'html5,silverlight,flash,html4',
    url: 'UploadHandler.ashx',
    max_file_size: '2mb',  
    chunk_size: '64kb',
    unique_names: false,
    filters: [{ title: "My File Types", extensions: "xlsx,xls,docx,doc"}],
    flash_swf_url: 'scripts/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url: 'scripts/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap',
    multiple_queues: true
});
```

Comment: found this very interesting, which I think answers my own question: https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the runtime you are using. Because of the setup `'html5,silverlight,flash,html4'` you specified, the HTML5 runtime is used first when available (which must be the case on Chrome). This runtime is the culprit.

If file extension is a serious issue to you, you can rely on Flash or SilverLight in priority: `'silverlight,flash,html5,html4'`. HTML5 may still be used, but only if SilverLight and Flash are both unavailable.